# Parent a Position X from Particular World to it's own transform xPosition

Tags: after-effects-expressions

I have a layer called Blue.

I applied CC Particular World to a ShapeLayer with an animated separated X Position (with 3 keyframes).

The thing is that the effect doesn't move along with the shape.
So either I animate the Producer features "Position X" with keyframes or I would parent this feature to xPosition.

I just don't know if this is possible and if so how?

I invented this script...

```
    thisComp.layer("Blue").effect("CC Particle World")("Position X").transform("xPosition")
```

it results in error!

Thank you for your help.

H.

Answer (score 3):

There's no property called `xPosition`, and `transform` is a property of a layer, not a method, but you're on the right track. The expression has to return an array of two values [x, y], and the components of the position are stored in an array like that too. The expression you want — if you're applying it to the layer position property — is this:

```js
xpos=thisComp.layer("Blue").effect("CC Particle World")("Position X");
ypos=transform.position[1];
[xpos, ypos]
```

That will apply the value of the `Position X` property of the effect to the **X** position of the layer, and the current **Y** value of the layer to the **Y**.

If you're trying to use the layer's **X** position on the effect's Position **X** property then you need to use:

```js
thisComp.layer("Blue").transform.position[0]
```

you only need one value for this property.

> **Pro Tip** a great way to learn how properties are accessed in expressions, as well as being a super quick and typo-free way of
>   creating them is to use the pickwhip. Next to the expression box
>   you'll see a curly icon. Click that and drag it to the property you
>   want to reference in your expression. So in the second case you could
>   drag it to the number for the **X** value of the layer's position and it
>   would give you the correct syntax for accessing it.
>
> [image]

A good place to learn more about expressions is Dan Ebbert's page: http://motionscript.com/

Comment: You're welcome, here is the meta: http://meta.video.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/syntax-highlighting, I hope we get a detailed explanation soon.